# Rename [vnext] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The term [vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vnext) is very generic, and can be applied to many things.  Microsoft uses the term to apply to their next version off various technologies, however someone created this tag specifically to apply to [.net-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-vnext) (there was also an [asp.net-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-vnext) tag created which at least is a little more specific).

I propose we rename this generic vnext to .net-vnext and alter the tag wiki information to indicate that it's a generic term relating to the next version of .net in development.  We can keep the current information about this, since Microsoft has not yet said what the specific version number will be in the next version (though likely 4.6 it looks like).

This will of course have to be kept up to date as new releases occur, but I don't see that being a problem as its a wiki.  vnext itself should also be re-created as a generic tag so it can't be coopted again for any specific vendor or technology.

EDIT:

As a side question, is it allowed to have a "placeholder" question to keep a tag referenced so it won't be deleted?  And by that i'm referring to the vNext tag, so that we can add commentary to the tag wiki and summary indicating that it should not be used for [.net-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-vnext) (Yes, I know.. user myopia.. but I have faith that some percentage of people read the tag summaries).  Perhaps there will even be legitimate vnext tagged questions somewhere down the line and the placeholder can go away.

EDIT:

Since someone has gone ahead and incorrectly retagged all the vnext questions without discussion, the tag no longer exists.. so this question is moot.

It can just go away...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276926/make-asp-net-vnext-a-synonym-for-asp-net-5

Comment: Even if you re-create it as a generic tag (with what questions??), it can still be coopted. See what twitter did/is doing to bootstrap.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Well, that's a different battle to be won...

Comment: "is moot.  It can just go away..." Hm, maybe delete it then? (Community just poked it.)

Comment: FYI, I just nuked [v-next] which popped up recently.

Comment: @JasonMArcher - yeah, every time someone recreates it, we have to keep on top of it.

Comment: The tag [just appeared again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103245/how-to-launch-vstudio-2015-rc), nuked it

Answer (score 2):

There is already a more popular tag in [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5), whose tag wiki states that it was "formerly codenamed ASP.NET vNext". The 19 instances of the [vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vnext) tag should be replaced with this more popular one.

Comment: asp.net and .net are different distinct technologies.  asp.net runs on .net, but .net is more than just asp.net

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch True but all uses of the vnext tag are about asp.net. EDIT: At least, they *were*, until someone went ahead and retagged them all just now.